# Merging results from different Cucumber HTML Reports

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, html-reports-jenkins

When running our test suite we perform a re-run which gives us 2 HTML reports at the end. What I am looking to do is have one final report so that I can then share it with stakeholders etc.

Can I merge the 2 reports so that in the first run a test had failed but in the second run it had passed, the report shows the test has passed?

I basically want to merge the reports to show a final outcome of the test run. Thanks

Comment: This may be a low tech way of doing it, but u can just copy and paste the contents of the report.js in the rerun folder into the report.js of the initial run folder. Just do not copy the first line (document.ready....) and the last line with the brackets )};.

Comment: @Richlewis 
Why dont you try using the `report_builder` gem? All you need to do is generate a `.json` report and the report will automatically merge all the `.json` files in one `.html`. The usage is pretty neatly explained in their repo page

Answer (score 1):

By only showing the report that passed you'd be throwing away a valuable piece of information: that there is an issue with the test suite making it flaky during execution. It can be something to do with the architecture or design of a particular test, or maybe the wait/sleep periods for some elements. Or, in some cases, the application we're testing has some sort of issue that a lot of times goes unchecked.

You should treat a failing report with as much respect as a passing one. I'd share with the stakeholders both reports and a short analysis of why the tests are failing in the first one(s), or why do they usually fail, and a proposal/strategy to fix the failure.

Regarding the merging of the reports, it can be done. You can, via a script that takes both reports, maybe extract the body of each, and, element by element only do a copy the passing one if the other is failing, or if both are failing, copy a failing one. But it looks like that would be an effort to hide a possible problem, and not to fix it from the ground up.

Edit:

> There is at least one lib that can help you achieve this,
>   [ReportBuilder](http://github.com/rajatthareja/ReportBuilder), or the Java equivalent:
>   [ReportBuilderJava](http://github.com/rajatthareja/ReportBuilderJava).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @FilipeFreire, just to clarify we are not looking to hide anything, if a test fails on the re run then we want to show it as failed (but sometimes tests will pass on the second run). We know this is an issue and is an ongoing thing to fix/investigate. It's the merging of the reports where i am a little stuck. Do you know of any tools that can help with this or any example scripts ? thanks

Comment: @Richlewis
that I know of, there is at least one lib that can help you achieve this, https://github.com/rajatthareja/ReportBuilder  (or the Java equivalent: https://github.com/rajatthareja/ReportBuilderJava )

Comment: The other option would be would investing maybe 1-2 days doing a JS or Python script doing this by hand.